# How to set variable row height (Item) in VCL ControlList in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, vcl

`TControlList` provides an `ItemHeight` property, but when I try to dynamically change it for a single row, it messes up the entire view.

The indicator is quite new, introduced in 2021, and there is practically no additional information for it.

I'm currently using the `OnBeforeDrawItem` event to attempt to change the height of a single row. However, trying to set a different height for a specific row affects the height of the rest. I tried two different solutions. I changed the height of only one selected element and also set the `ItemHeight` property for each of them at a different height.

The `ItemHeight` property appears to affect the entire control, not a single row. I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to dynamically change the height of a single row.

The description on the Embarcadero website does not answer my question ([Using VCL TControl List Control](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_VCL_TControlList_Control)).

```
procedure TForm9.ControlList1BeforeDrawItem(AIndex: Integer; ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; AState: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
   if AIndex = 3 then
      ControlList1.ItemHeight := 30
   else
      ControlList1.ItemHeight := 70;
end;
```

I am using Delphi 12 (Athens)

Comment: The link at the end of your q is erroneous, but in [the actual document](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Using_VCL_TControlList_Control), the last sentence of the very first paragraph in the document says: "This list represents a single selection list and **all items are visually of the same height and width**." Ergo, what you need cannot be done with the `TControlList` control. Maybe you want to look into [Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView)

Comment: I was guided by a similar control (TListView) in FireMonkey, which is why I didn't notice this caveat in the description. Thank you.